# "Cannot infer type - type annotations needed", but the type is already known

Tags: rust

I've been practicing on LC where I hit the [following issue](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f2c8cfc94b4458df200fefe45bd552a).

```rust
pub fn largest_rectangle_area(heights: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut widths = vec![(0usize, heights.len()); heights.len()];
    let mut stack = vec![];

    for (idx, &x) in heights.iter().enumerate() {
        while let Some(&pos) = stack.last() {
            if x >= heights[pos] {
                break;
            }

            widths[pos].1 = idx;
            stack.pop();
        }

        stack.push(idx);
    }

    todo!()
}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/lib.rs:11:13
   |
11 |             widths[pos].1 = idx;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: type must be known at this point
```

What's even stranger is that if I do a `widths[pos] = (0, idx);` first, [then the error disappears](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a541fcfbf1ea82027ab105884a25db04):

```rust
pub fn largest_rectangle_area(heights: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut widths = vec![(0, heights.len()); heights.len()];
    let mut stack = vec![];

    for (idx, &x) in heights.iter().enumerate() {
        while let Some(&pos) = stack.last() {
            if x >= heights[pos] {
                break;
            }

            widths[pos] = (0, idx); // do a full update
            stack.pop();
        }

        stack.push(idx);
    }
    stack.clear();

    for (idx, &x) in heights.iter().enumerate().rev() {
        while let Some(&pos) = stack.last() {
            if x >= heights[pos] {
                break;
            }

            widths[pos].0 = idx + 1; // now it's fine to use `.0`
            stack.pop();
        }

        stack.push(idx);
    }
    todo!()
}
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in the compiler ?

#### Update

@ [Ömer Erden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1601571/%C3%96mer-erden) discovered, that it fails to infer the type of `pos` which should be `usize` as it's coming from `enumerate()` indirectly.

It seems pretty strange because it fails to infer the type of `pos` when doing `widths[pos].1 = idx;`, but succeeds when doing `widths[pos] = (0, idx);`

[He also managed to create more minimal MCVE:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=556f4f6503e841ae56b313f01534fe13)

```rust
fn _some_fn() {
    let mut widths = vec![(0usize, 0usize); 100];
    let mut stack = vec![];
    //let mut stack:Vec<usize> = vec![]; //why explicit type definition needed

    let a = stack.pop().unwrap();
    let idx = 0usize;
    widths[a].1 = idx;

    stack.push(idx);
}
```

#### Bug Report

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90252

Comment: It cannot find the index `I` type from `Index<I>` type, if you define your stack as `let mut stack:Vec<usize> = vec![];` then it will work, here is the implementation(https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#2460-2467). It is clear that there is no type declaration for your `pos` variable , it needs to be a type that implements `SliceIndex<_>`, in your case it is `usize`

Comment: @ÖmerErden thanks, that seems to be the issue. I wonder why it fails to infer that `pos` is `usize` in some cases, while it succeeds in others.

Comment: I checked the code over again, there is still things to consider, this still might be a bug or a limitation. Looks like my comment doesn't cover the whole story since `idx` is a `usize` from `enumeration`, the type of the stack should already inferred via this statement `stack.push(idx);`

Comment: Here I've created much more minimal example to express the idea: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45b0bf9e9fb022eefe1d51d1bce93c1f ,  I assume that the some of the type-inference steps are missing.

Comment: @ÖmerErden *why compiler is not even aware this needs to be mutable* - the explanation for that is that mutability checks come as part of the borrow checking, which is only performed after successful type checking. Since type inference (and with it type checking) failed, borrow check cannot be performed.

Comment: @user4815162342 Ohh, that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why the compiler *is unable to elide the type*, but you can manually annotate it with some easy changes:

```rust
pub fn largest_rectangle_area(heights: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut widths = vec![(0usize, heights.len()); heights.len()];
    let mut stack = vec![];

    for (idx, &x) in heights.iter().enumerate() {
        while let Some(&pos) = stack.last() {
            if x >= heights[pos] {
                break;
            }
            let at_pos: &mut (usize, usize) = &mut widths[pos];
            at_pos.1 = idx;
            stack.pop();
        }

        stack.push(idx);
    }

    todo!()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44467751c137bbdc12b944513b10329c)

Comment: Yeah, but why do I have to add the type *here* ? If I add the type annotation at the `let mut widths: Vec<(usize, usize)> = ...` it still complains with the same error.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, it looks like a compiler limitation or error. Most probably you could report it since it could be helpful. No harm done anyway since it is easy solvable.